# str_replace and uppercase or lowercase

Tags: php, str-replace

I wanted to know the best way to find and replace a word in php depending uppercase and lowercase.

I have actually:

```
$chain = "My long chain";
$keyword = "My";
str_replace($keyword, "<span class='highlight1'>".$keyword."</span>", $chain);
```

It works for `My` but not for `my` or `MY`.

How to do that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: [manual say: "This function is case-sensitive. Use str_ireplace() for case-insensitive replace." ouu the manual- its magical](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: This question is useful. We should modify the title/description and reopen it. OP wants to replace all variations of the words (different case combinations) to get replaced with the given replacement, and preserve the actual casing in the result. So, simply doing str_ireplace is not a solution. The accepted answer by raina77ow shows it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want just to normalize all the forms of some word/expression, use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for case-insensitive replacements. Actually, a lot of string functions in PHP have case-insensitive siblings - with `i` prepended to the 'action part' in their names.

If you want to preserve the original casing, use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with case-insensitivity modifier instead:

```
$pattern = preg_quote($keyword);
$result  = preg_replace("/($pattern)/i", 
  '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $chain);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2XhCvR) (I have replaced `class` with `style` for clearer demonstration). Note that even though `$1` expr here is in the single quotes literal, it's still interpolated.